# mysql query going for full table scan

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE APA_Pended_Demand apd
INNER JOIN APA_Generic_Demand_Details agd
    ON agd.demandID = apd.demandID 
SET apd.genericDemandId = agd.genericDemandId
WHERE apd.isPend = 1 AND
      agd.genericDemandId != '' AND
      agd.genericDemandId IS NOT NULL AND
      apd.reactivateDate > UTC_TIMESTAMP() AND
      agd.status < 300 AND
      apd.ID BETWEEN 280001 AND 290000 ;
```

The above query is going for full table scan.So can anyone please help me in sorting this query

Comment: And an index on the `demandID` columns.  And if that doesn't work, maybe add indices to the columns appearing in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `apgnricdmnddetils_prdcttype` (`productType`),
 KEY `apgnricdmnddtils_srcereqrle` (`sourceReqRole`),
 KEY `apgnericdemnddetils_methdin` (`methodIn`),
 KEY `apgnricdemnddetils_bndnresn` (`abandonReason`),
 KEY `IX1_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`status`,`customerReference`,`policyNo`,`genericDemandId`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX2_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`status`,`schemeReference`,`genericDemandId`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX3_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`status`,`aggregationKey`,`genericDemandId`) USING BTREE,

Comment: KEY `IX4_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`status`,`initiator`,`aggregationKey`,`genericDemandId`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX5_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`status`,`policyNo`,`genericDemandId`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX6_APA_Generic_Demand_Details_Status` (`status`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX7_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`genericDemandId`),

Comment: KEY `IX8_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`initiator`,`status`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `IX9_APA_Generic_Demand_Details` (`customerReference`,`status`) USING BTREE,

Comment: The above are the indexes but when i try to see explain the query it says indexing not using